# Update Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-forms

I am working on project with symfony 3 and doctrine .
I have a many to many relationship between Pack and Produit :

Pack Entity :

```
class Pack
{ 
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection | Produit[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Produit", inversedBy="packs")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="link_pack")
     */
    private $produits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->produits = new ArrayCollection();

    }


    /**
     * @return Produit[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getProduits()
    {
        return $this->produits;
    }

    public function addProduit(Produit $produit)
    {
        if ($this->produits->contains($produit)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->produits[] =  $produit;
    }

    public function removeProduit(Produit $produit)
    {
        if (! $this->produits->contains($produit)) {
            return;
        }
       return $this->produits->removeElement($produit);
    }
}
```

Produit Entity :

```
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection | Pack[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pack", mappedBy="produits")
     */
    private $packs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->packs = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * @return Pack[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPacks()
    {
        return $this->packs;
    }

    public function addPack(Pack $pack)
    {
        if ($this->packs->contains($pack)) {
            return;
        }
        $pack->addProduit($this);
        $this->packs[] =  $pack;
    }
}
```

I want to assign products to a pack , so I have a form that contains products in a select field. (the pack and products are created before).

The form type :

```
class PackAffectProduitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('produits', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Produit::class,        
            'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                    'multiple' => true,       
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Pack::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

The controller :

```
public function affectProduitsAction(Pack $pack, Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(PackAffectProduitType::class, $pack);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        dump($pack);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            dump($pack);
            $em->flush();
           // ...
        }
       //...
    }
```

The problem is when I select the products and submit, It assigns the selected products to the pack but the products assigned before are deleted. I want them to still assigned, So how to solve this problem ?

Comment: The answer deleted was helpful. Can you re post it

Comment: I reposted it, I just removed the (I think) unrelevant part since it was overkill because of your FormType's class_name already being Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want your view to add OR remove values, if you manually generate your field view structure, you need not to forget to fill already set values (e.g. the products previously added to the `Pack`).

For example by adding the `selected` attribute to the choices of your `select`. Doing so will pre-fill your field with current values therefore removing at submit only those which have been deliberately unselected.

- If you don't want your view to display nor know anything about already set `Produit` entities on this pack and just blindly perform adds, you can add `mapped => false` to your field options and handle manually the addition of your products to your pack in your controller.

This will only allow you to add though, since it does not have knowledge of already set values, and you would have to make another case/action to perform deletion. Above way is better in my opinion.

In this last case, your controller would look like :

```
public function affectProduitsAction(Pack $pack, Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(PackAffectProduitType::class, $pack);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if(is_array($form->get('produits')->getData()){
            foreach($form->get('produits')->getData() as $produit){
                $pack->addProduit($produit);
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
       // ...
    }
   //...
}
```

And your FormType :

```
class PackAffectProduitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('produits', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Produit::class,     
            'mapped' => false,   
            'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                    'multiple' => true,       
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Pack::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'by_reference' => false` option to your form, it will force to use setters and getters from your entity

Comment: I added it and i did not work, the first answer is the right answer. I did not know why he has deleted it.